# Is there a way to distinguish normal loop termination from break termination in Rust?

Tags: for-loop, rust, control-flow

Idiomatic `for/else` in rust:

In Python, I can use `for`/`else` to check whether or not a `for` loop terminated at a `break` statement or finished 'normally':

```
prod = 1
for i in range(1, 10):
    prod *= i
    if prod > 123:
        break
else:
    print("oops! loop terminated without break.")
```

Is there a similar way to do that in Rust? This is the closest I have come, but it is not particularly similar.

```
let mut prod = 1u64;
let mut found = false;
for i in 1..10 {
    prod *= i;
    if prod > 123 {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if !found {
    println!("oops! loop terminated without break.");
}
```

There seems to be a discussion about this on [rust internals](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-break-with-value-in-for-while-loops/11208); however, that is more about future possibilities than what is idiomatic.

In Python, idiomatic code is called *pythonic* - is there a similar word for idiomatic Rust code?

Comment: Not an answer, but when I face this need, I immediately think whether I really need this - or an iterator or maybe a `loop` with break-with-value will do better.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman would you have any suggestion in this particular example (in my real case i iterate over a `Vec<u64>` and not a range)? i am not interested in the `prod`, but in the index of the vector when the product becomes too large.

Comment: I would probably use `enumerate().try_fold()`. I won't post that as an answer since the question was in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Rust 1.65, you can break out of blocks, optionally with a value. [Cases like that were even mentioned in the RFC as a motivation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2046-label-break-value.md#motivation):

```rust
let value = 'found: {
    for i in 1..2 {
        prod *= i;
        if prod > 123 {
            break 'found Some(prod);
        }
    }
    println!("oops! loop terminated without break.");
    None
};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84e9c554a210f1ba89f3a4bdb738f8a6).

Comment: great, thank you! once this feature is stable this should become the accepted answer.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Stabilized for Rust 1.65!

Comment: rust 1.65 with that feature is now out! https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#break-from-labeled-blocks

Answer (score 4):

A simple `None` initialized value provides a reasonably convenient way to do this:

```
let mut prod = 1u64;
let mut value = None;
for i in 1..10 {
    prod *= i;
    if prod > 123 {
        value = Some(prod);
        break;
    }
}
if value.is_none() {
    println!("oops! loop terminated without break.");
}
```

Comment: It may seem silly coming from me, as I wrote _two_ answers here, but I think this is _The Way_.

Comment: very nice indeed! although the difference to my original attempt is small, i prefer this one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how idiomatic it is but sometimes I write this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut prod = 1u64;
    let value = 'found: loop {
        for i in 1..2 {
            prod *= i;
            if prod > 123 {
                break 'found Some(prod);
            }
        }
        println!("oops! loop terminated without break.");
        break 'found None;
    };
    //Here value is Option<u64> with the result.
}
```

That is, an outer labelled loop that can be broken from inside when you are ready. You can even give it a type with the `break` label value` syntax.

Comment: this works. although the outer `loop` does not look that nice. even if it never really loops...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: I agree it is not ideal. I tend to forget the ending `break` and have an infinite loop.

Comment: clippy agrees with both of us: `error: this loop never actually loops`. had to decorate it with `#[allow(clippy::never_loop)]`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: If you don't need the break value you can loop with `for _ in [()]`, but this time Rustc itself complains with: "warning: for loop over a single element".

Comment: [label-break-value](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48594). [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=831005fdea0499a2dfe33c21f3a86d4b).

Answer (score 3):

Usually you can translate to some iterator pattern instead of the `for` loop:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut prod = 1u64;
    if let Some(i) = (1..10)
        .filter_map(|i| {
            prod *= i;
            if prod > 123 {
                Some(i)
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
        .next()
    {
        println!("item found for {i}");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ee3227896000ca597331d41e52b855e1)

Comment: also nice! i tried to make an iterator-based approach work but found nothing. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have seen people use a temporal locale function, Javascript style:

```
fn main() {
    let mut prod = 1u64;
    let value = (|| {
        for i in 1..10 {
            prod *= i;
            if prod > 123 {
                return Some(prod);
            }
        }
        println!("oops! loop terminated without break.");
        None
    })();
}
```

You define a temporary function and immediately call it, this way you can have `return` inside. This trick is also used to propagate errors with `?`, while the `try {}` statement is not stable.

Comment: also a good idea! but again... a bit verbose (may just seem to me that way because i am much more used to python...).

Answer (score -5):

How about this?

```
let result = {
    for i in 1..10 {
        prod *= i;
        if prod > 123 {
            Ok(())
        }
    }
    Err(())
}
```

Comment: But your variable `result` is never used because you `return` finishes the function, not the inner expression.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks. Its been a while since I've done any actual rust...

Comment: tried it. it does not compile: `error[E0308]: mismatched type`.